# TypeScript Lamba Function error 'return outside function definition'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I'm getting a 'return outside function definition" error while using lambda function in it. Typescript file compiles without any error, however, the compiled JavaScript file throws the above error.

In TypeScript (without any error):

```
var lambdaFunction = (name1: string) => {return name1};
console.log(lambdaFunction("Jack"));
```

Is getting translated to following code in JavaScript:

```
var lambdaFunction = (name1) => { return name1; };
console.log(lambdaFunction("Jack"));
```

showing error at the arrow =>. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're compiling to ES6, but are trying to run the code on a platform that doesn't support arrow function (i.e. is actually an ES5 runtime). Upgrade your JS runtime or tell TypeScript to compile to `--target ES5`